# Drawing 3D polygon using vertex array

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vertex-array

I have a short program which draw a 3D `GL.GL_QUADS`  ,  here its `display()` method -

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        ....
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS); // of the color cube

        // Top-face
        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // green
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Bottom-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f); // orange
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Front-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // red
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Back-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // yellow
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Left-face
        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // blue
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Right-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // violet
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            ....
}
```

Now I want to change the above drawing to "Vertex Arrays" mode and to get same results  , so I did the following  :

1. Created a `float` array of all the vertices coodinates of the `GL.GL_QUADS` .
2. `put` this array to a `Buffer` .
3. Tell OpenGL where the vertices are (8 vertices) .
4. Tell OpenGL which indices to draw .

Here is the main code  I wrote (**edited**) -

```
public class DisplayWithArray extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener,
        KeyListener {

    private float[] cubeVertices = { 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,

            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f,

            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f,

            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f };

    private float[] colorVertices ={ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    // 1st edit  - 24 positions of the GL.GL_QUADS
    private int[] indices = new int[24] ;

    private IntBuffer indicesBuf ;  
}
public DisplayWithArray(GLCapabilities capabilities, int width, int height) {
        for (int i=0 ; i<24 ; i++) {
            this.indices[i] = i ; 
    }
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
            ...
        final GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            ...
        setupPointer(gl);
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        final GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        // draw
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}

public void setupPointer(GL gl) {

        FloatBuffer tmpVerticesBuf = BufferUtil
                .newFloatBuffer(cubeVertices.length);
        ;
        FloatBuffer tmpColorVerticesBuf = BufferUtil
                .newFloatBuffer(colorVertices.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < cubeVertices.length; i++) {
            tmpVerticesBuf.put(cubeVertices[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < colorVertices.length; i++) {
        tmpColorVerticesBuf.put(colorVertices[i]);
    }
        tmpVerticesBuf.rewind();
        tmpColorVerticesBuf.rewind();
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, tmpVerticesBuf);
        gl.glColorPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, tmpColorVerticesBuf);
        // Indices of polygon
        IntBuffer tmpIndicesBuf = BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(this.indices.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            tmpIndicesBuf.put(indices[i]);
        }
        tmpIndicesBuf.rewind();

        indicesBuf = tmpIndicesBuf ; 
}
```

When I run it I get an exception `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glDrawElements(): GL_INVALID_ENUM   at DisplayWithArray.display(DisplayWithArray.java:152)`

point to the line   - `gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_QUADS, indices.length, GL.GL_INT, indicesBuf);`

What is wrong here  ?

**Edit:**

I changed the `indices` array to range [0,5]  - according to 6 face of the `GL.GL_QUADS`.
And extend `tmpColorVerticesBuf` array to 72 indices (4 times each color)  .

Still I have same exception as mentioned above  .

**Edit 2:** (now it works well)
Solve by comparing between `cubeVertices` and `colorVertices`  sizes (72 each array)  , and in `display()` use `gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24)` (24 elements of size 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that your arrays are not the same size. Your vertex position array has 24 vec3's in it, while your color array only has *six*. So when your index array says "6", it's going to try to access the 7'th entry in an array with 6 elements. Hence the crash.

Every array uses the *same index*. Therefore, if you want to have colors and positions, then *each color* must have a single corresponding position. And vice-versa. You can't have 6 colors working with 32 positions. Nor can each attribute use different indices. If you're doing indexed rendering, they *all* must use the same index.

Comment: I re-arranged the arrays (now it same sizes) as I mentioned in the edited post  , I wish you would take a look   .